# How to center an image in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, label

i was trying to put [this logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKQfV.png) on the middle of the window (horizontally), but i couldn't manage it. I tried to "anchor= CENTER" thingy but i think its not working on images.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x500')
root.resizable(0,0)
root.title("Youtube Video Downloader")

img = PhotoImage(file="logo.png",)
logo =Label(root, image=img, anchor= CENTER).grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)

root.mainloop()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `.pack()` instead of `.grid(...)`.

Comment: Thank you! I changed it with ".pack(side=TOP)" and it worked

Comment: If you want to keep using grid, you can add `root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)` below `root.title` and then change sticky to EW.